# Java script to show and hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010

My requirement is pretty simple, it has to check for a variable and display/hide a class accordingly. It is on a sharepoint publishing page. 
Using the following snippet is not working.

```
if ( source = 'show')
{
$('.classshide').hide();
}
else
{
$('.classsshow').hide();
}
```

It works only when the source variable is show and it should work the otherway too, when it is not equal to show or equal to hide, please hide the classshow.

Comment: You need to change `if ( source = 'show')` to `if ( source == 'show')`

Comment: that not even working for the first case if i use '==' in place of '='.

Comment: Are you sure the `source` is the correct values?

Comment: yes, it is already getting defined on the page and i could clearly see the variable as show or hide. and i am just pulling it into my java script to check which one it is show/hide.

Comment: If it is definitely correctly defined, then it is really strange that the equality operators aren't working...

Answer (score 2):

Your equality test is wrong.

```
if ( source = 'show')
```

should be

```
if ( source == 'show')
```

or it could be

```
if ( source === 'show') //if source is a string and you don't want type coercion
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use strict comparison `===`. It is faster because it doesn't have to convert the `type` when it compares the `value` of the variable.

*Edit:*

```
// get what the current state of hide/show is
var source = $('.classhide').length === 0 ? 'show' : 'hide';

if ( source === 'show') {
    $('.classshide').hide();
} else {
    $('.classsshow').hide();
}
```

Comment: Not working. Now, it not even works for the first case as well. Nothing happens.

Comment: @svs Then I have a feeling `source` isn't defined with an actual value when it gets used in the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the equality (`==`) or strict equality (`===`) operator to compare the `source` variable to "show" in your if statement. Because you mention needing to display as well as hide the classes, I'm guessing you want to alternate which classes are displayed, so I adjusted the rest of the code accordingly.

```
if ( source === 'show' )
{
    $('.classshide').hide();
    $('.classsshow').show();
}
else if ( source === 'hide' )
{
    $('.classsshow').hide();
    $('.classshide').show();
}
else // for some reason source is neither 'show' or 'hide'
{    //default to the logic for if it is 'hide'
    $('.classsshow').hide();
    $('.classshide').show();
}
```

Comment: For some reason, == or === not working for me. It checks for at least for the first if condition if i use only = and  else fails.

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? Are you setting the variable before the if block, and are you setting it to the correct value?

Comment: the variable is getting defined within the page and i am just pulling that into my script to check in if block.

Comment: Can you place `alert(source);` before the if block and let me know what it says? There might be something wrong with the way it's being defined...

Comment: it is showing it in 'view source' but when i added alert, it is not showing it up in alert.

Comment: Ok so that is the problem. With the code I posted it should go to the `else`. Can you update your question with the code that sets `source` so we can try to figure out why it's losing its value?

Comment: yes, that was the issue, by the time java script triggers, source wasn't getting defined, moving the code which defines the source variable at the top on the page body seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks for throwing ideas....